# 1920’s house turning commercial

Tags: floor, load

I am needing to ensure my live load is 100lbs per sf. I have some heavy freezers and equipment that I want to make sure have enough support and don’t break through the floor!

What is the framework set up for 100 lbs per sf? The house is pier and beam, so we can get in the crawl space to add extra support pretty easily.

Comment: Probably a lot more than you have now.  Modern homes have a live load of about 40 pounds per sq ft.  1920 might not be near there.

Comment: `100 lbs per sf`  would be a special design

Comment: Rather than rely on good meaning folks from the internet, you really need to have an engineer  take a look.  If you don't and there is an issue your insurance may use it as a reason not to pay.  If you haven't looked into insurance, an engineering report may be needed to get insurance.

Comment: Turning commercial acttually takes it out of the home improvement arena.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about home improvement.